# Mysql (innodb) delete from joined tables low perfomance issue

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

Here's the question: I have two tables, one of them is loaded from file and then they compared for unique records:

```
DELETE a.* FROM %s a INNER JOIN %s b using (domain);
```

But this operation is extremely slow. The tables that compared are 50k and 20k records respectively. I turned of autocommit before running this query but there's no large boost to perfomance. So, what can I do to speed up this operation to any reasonable time? Thank you!

Comment: Have you placed an index on `a(domain)` and `b(domain)`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, thanks a lot! Now It works perfectly, but I dont get it - I thought indexes are used for searcing records, but here we are comparing them one by one, isn't it?

Comment: Indexes are also used in join operations.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, I see. Much appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, it had to "search" for which record to delete.